# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am migrating a website on IIS 7.5 from IIS 6.0. In IIS 6.0 i was using UrlRewriting and code is working fine. I have configured the website through Classic Asp.net app pool. I have also  updated the rewrite rules in the web config as per IIS 7.

I am getting this error when i want to open a page in the browser.

> Server Error in '/' Application. Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   value Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: value
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value]
>   System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry..ctor(String key, Object value,
>   CacheDependency dependency, CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemovedHandler,
>   DateTime utcAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan slidingExpiration,
>   CacheItemPriority priority, Boolean isPublic) +11691362
>   System.Web.Caching.CacheInternal.DoInsert(Boolean isPublic, String
>   key, Object value, CacheDependency dependencies, DateTime
>   utcAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan slidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority
>   priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemoveCallback, Boolean replace)
>   +144    System.Web.Caching.Cache.Insert(String key, Object value) +110    URLRewriter.Config.RewriterConfiguration.GetConfig() +247
>   URLRewriter.ModuleRewriter.Rewrite(String requestedPath,
>   HttpApplication app) +178
>   URLRewriter.BaseModuleRewriter.BaseModuleRewriter_AuthorizeRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +158
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +80    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270

Any ideas to resolve this issue or Why the issue is coming?

Thanks In Advance
Laxman

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an error in your `.aspx` file which is triggered when you launch `this.DataBind()` in your `PageLoad()`.

I think that you are trying to get the parameter `value` from am object which is null, something like `<%# YourObject.value %>` and `YourObject` is null. After that you get `ArgumentNullException`.

Search your `.aspx` for the `value` and make sure that every instance of the owner is not null.